# How to update a 2d numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following array:

```
array([[ 0.        , -1.22474487,  1.40182605],
       [ 1.22474487,  0.        , -0.53916387],
       [-1.22474487,  1.22474487, -0.86266219]])
```

What is the best way to parse each of its elements and assign a string depending on the value? For example: if value < 0 then set "LOW" else set "HIGH"?

Comment: You can't assign a string to a numpy array that already contains numbers. Do you want to create a new array or, list-of-lists with the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `a` is your `array` use

```
import numpy as np

np.where(a<0,'LOW','HIGH')
```

Edit:
When you have 3 choices you can do something like

```
b = np.where(a < 0.,'LOW','HIGH').astype('S7') 

c = np.where((-1. < a) & (a < 1.), 'MIDDLE',b)
```